# Can one use Clutter with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, clutter, python-bindings

Are there Python 3 bindings for Clutter? If so, how can I get them and use them?

Comment: I just found this documentation: https://clutter-and-mx-under-python3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html which seems to be useful for using clutter with py3. HIH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by Lattyware, the way to use Clutter in Python 3 is by installing "GObject introspection" data and allowing GObject to dynamically generate the bindings to the original C library.

On Ubuntu 11.10, install both Python 3 GObject and the GObject introspection data for clutter:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gobject gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

On Ubuntu 12.04 and later, the `python3-gobject` package has been renamed to `python3-gi`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gi gir1.2-clutter-1.0
```

If you want to install the GTK+ Clutter library:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gi gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0
```

If using a `virtualenv` virtual Python environment, use the following command, which allows Python to find the GObject introspection libraries:

```
virtualenv env -p python3 --system-site-packages
```

To use Clutter or GtkClutter in Python 3:

```
from gi.repository import Clutter
from gi.repository import GtkClutter
```

The package `gi.repository` is a special package which dynamically generates these Python classes.

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather, the answer is to use [GObject](http://wiki.clutter-project.org/wiki/GObject_Concepts) rather than direct bindings, and [PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) appears to have a [Python 3 branch](http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/log/?h=py3k) that apparently works - not that I have used it personally.

You might also want to see [this question on using PyGObject with python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065310/how-to-install-pygobject-with-python-3-support).

Comment: I already have python-gobject working with Python 3. I want to know if it's possibly to use clutter with Python 3.